# information in multidimensional replacing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, format

Hi im making this program that creates employees and saves their information. i made this method in one class to store some of the information it receives, but the problem is, it overwrites the information that gets passed in. this is the method `

```
int employeeSize = 1;

public void employeeInfo(int ID , double hours, int salary){
    double [][] empInfo = new double[employeeList.size()][3];
        for(int row = 0; row < empInfo.length; row++){
            empInfo[ID-1][0] = ID;  

        }
        for(int row = 0; row < empInfo.length; row++){
                empInfo[ID-1][1] = hours;

        }
        for(int row = 0; row < empInfo.length; row++){
                empInfo[ID-1][2] = Double.parseDouble(f.format(getPay(hours, salary)));

        }
        //if(employeeSize == employeeList.size()){
            printInfo(empInfo);
            totalPay(empInfo);
            totalHours(empInfo);
        //}
            employeeSize++;
    }`
```

this is how its being used in the other class, it asks for  the employees hours for a number of times depending on how many employees are being added, and the other information gets passed through.

```
for(int i = 0; i <employeesToAdd; i++){
    double hours = getADouble(scanner, "\nEnter the hours for "+employees.names(i)+": > ");
    employees.employeeInfo(employees.id(i), hours,employees.getSalary(i));
}
```

**this is the result of it being printed.**

```
Enter the hours for j: > 42
1.0 42.0    1757.21 0.0 0.0 0.0
This is the total pay: 1757
This is the total hour: 42.0
Enter the hours for d: > 41
0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 41.0    1296.88
This is the total pay: 1296
This is the total hour: 41.0
```

i would like to also format the print out to be

```
Enter the hours for j: > 42
Enter the hours for d: > 41

1.0 42.0    1757.21
2.0 41.0    1296.88
This is the total pay: 3054
This is the total hour: 83.0
```

this is the method that prints the array

```
public void printInfo(double[][]array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print("\t"+array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by infos being overwritten? Perhaps making them immutable?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things which can probably help you here; but I'll go over your question one aspect at a time.

You say that some of your parametric data is overwritten in your method; this is often because, in Java, all object parameters are passed by *reference*, not by *value*. What this means is that, under the hood, passing an object as a parameter is really just passing a pointer to the location in memory of that object, and inside and outside of the method, all operations are on the same object. To get around this, you usually need to do something called *deep copying*, or copying the structure and contents of the object to a new item. The other good advice I can give you, though I don't see where the problem is just yet (it's 11:18 PM over here), is to avoid using static and global-scope variables for tasks like that, as they tend to lean to problems like this. It's better to adjust/refactor your method to simply return the entry that must be made, preferably in a collection instead of an array.

The second item I will suggest is for your output formatting. What you might consider using for a case like this is the Java Streaming API. A stream iterates over every item it contains, performs a sequence of defined operations on it, and ends in a terminal method. They are new to Java 8. For what you're doing, you might do something like this:

```
 Arrays.stream(array).forEach(a -> Arrays.stream(a).forEach(a2 -> System.out.print("\t" + item))
```

This allows for efficient mapping and sorting, all of which are documented in the API under the entry "Stream". For lists and sets (which I recommend over an array in any event), you can just call Collection.stream() instead, which they all implement. As for their ordering, that's a question of ordering your calls.

I hope I've helped. I'll try and come back to this when I have time tomorrow.